# How to get bitmap of a Marker in Google Maps v2?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

In Google Maps v2 for Android, there is a **Marker** object.  It has an icon field that allows you to set a drawable for this marker.  However, I would like to get the icon that was previously set on a marker.  Is there a way to do this?  I have dozens of markers on the map, and I want to calculate the boundaries of the drawables of each of those markers, in order to avoid collisions.

Thank you,
Igor

Comment: For you, I left the more full comment at [here in Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14451352/1983061).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below is the sample code in the demo files of Google Maps APIS v2.
This shows us the HOW TO USE the custom icon in Google Maps.

```
    private void addMarkersToMap() {
        // Uses a colored icon. this is default icon.
        mBrisbane = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BRISBANE)
                .title("Brisbane")
                .snippet("Population: 2,074,200")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        // **Uses a custom icon.**
        mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(SYDNEY)
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

**R.drawable.arrow** will be your custom icon : Make your icon using the Graphic software(such as Photoshop)and then insert your icon into the folder of **res/drwable** in your project.

Comment: Hi @IgorGanapolsky did you find any solution to get the marker width and height dynamically ???

Answer (score 0):

**This is help for me**

```
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
```