# how to get current location Gmaps V2 ..?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am new to android and i want to display my current location like "johar town Lahore,  Pakistan". Any help please ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to get current latitude and longitude use:** `LocationManager`

```
LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria cr = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
        Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            double lat=location.getLatitude();
        double lng=location.getLongitude();
        }
```

**pass current latitude and longitude to following method it will return you address !**

```
public List<Address> getAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {

            Geocoder geocoder;

            geocoder = new Geocoder(youractivityname.this);
            if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                //testing address below 

                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                Log.d("TAG", "address = " + address + ", city =" + city
                        + ", country = " + country);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return addresses;
    }
```

Comment: List<Address> and passangerHome.this are unknown .?

Comment: passangerHome.this=youractivityname.this

Comment: import java.util.List;

Comment: import android.location.Address;

Comment: Check the gps is switched on in your device. Then only you can able to get latitude and longitude for current location.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find your location, so follow this posts:
[Current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005223/android-google-map-api-v2-current-location) and here [Current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418135/google-maps-current-location-marker-and-accuracy-radius-overlay).

Then to find places, have a look here
[List of places around user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181812/get-list-of-places-surrounding-users-current-location)